# Is there a way to insert into a boost::multi_index with more than one hint?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

I have a `multi_index` with 5 indices.
Using `insert` with a hint improves performance noticeably compared to no hint.
The `insert` is in the critical path, and my code is in a situation where it could give hints for all the indices (e.g: in one case, I have to check for duplicity beforehand, so I already have the insertion point for that index).
Even if the hints are not always all accurate, I'd get a dramatic performance improvement.

How can I insert into a `boost::multi_index` giving more than one hint, short of rolling my own tailored container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid Boost.MultiIndex does not support the functionality you describe, nor is there a way you can get an equivalent effect on your own. If you feel like it please submit a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/boostorg/multi_index/issues) so that I can consider it in the lib backlog.